# Date Popup does not close when press ESC or click outside the window

Tags: angular

Date Popup does not close when I press **ESC** or click outside the window. 
This scenario happens only if `ngbDatepicker` splits into two parts for the additional beautification.
Any help will be appreciated. **Angular 7** is the version currently used.

```html
<div class="input-group input-margin-top">
    <div class="clearable">
        <i class="clearable-clear mdi mdi-calendar-text"  (click)="toggleDatepicker($event)" ></i>
        <input class="input-style"  #ngbDp name="dp" [readonly]="true"  [(ngModel)]="start_date"  ngbDatepicker
         (ngModelChange)="onStartDateChange($event)">
    </div>
</div>
<div #calendarStart class="date-picker popup">
    <div class="close-button-row">
        <button class="ml-auto" (click)="toggleDatepicker($event)">
            <i class="mdi mdi-close"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row-center">Start Date</div>
    <ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="start_date" (navigate)="date = $event.next" name="ngbDp"
        [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" (ngModelChange)="onStartDateChange($event)">
    </ngb-datepicker>
</div>
```